# Is there any way to show the records using same query?

Tags: sql

I want to list out notices which are not sent. So I tried the query like below. But its showing wrong result. Is there any way to show notices which are not sent using the following query.

```
SELECT 
    vtn.*,
    vn.id as notice_id,
    vn.vnotice_datetime as sent_notice_time
FROM 
    vtemplates vt 
    LEFT JOIN vtemplate_notices vtn ON( vtn.vtemplate_id = vt.id)
   LEFT JOIN vnotices vn ON(vn.vtemplate_notice_id = vtn.id AND vn.vnotice_datetime IS nULL)
    LEFT JOIN violations v ON ( v.vtemplate_id = vt.id)
WHERE 
    v.id = 1

Records in a violation_notices table are as follows:
--------------------------------------------------------------
id  vtemplate_notice_id desc   vnotice_datetime   created_on
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      1                test1   22/12/2018 05:30    22/12/2018
```

Expected Result:

```
id    vtemplate_id   created_on   notice_id  sent_notice_time
---------------------------------------------------------------
2       1             23/12/2018   NULL           NULL
3       1             24/12/2018   NULL           NULL
4       1             24/12/2018   NULL           NULL
```

Actual Result:

```
id    vtemplate_id   created_on   notice_id  sent_notice_time
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       1             22/12/2018   NULL           NULL
2       1             23/12/2018   NULL           NULL
3       1             24/12/2018   NULL           NULL
4       1             24/12/2018   NULL           NULL
```

In actual result, it shows first record (which should not come) for which vnotice_datetime is NOT NULL but still it's showing.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or test the joined column `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

e.g

```
SELECT * FROM violations
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM notifications
    WHERE violation_id = violations.id
 )

SELECT v.*, n.* FROM violations v
LEFT JOIN notifications n
    ON n.violation_id = v.id
WHERE n.violation_id IS NULL
```

Comment: If I did not send first 2 notices and select 3rd then it should show me 3rd, 4th & so on.How should I achieve this then?

Answer (score 0):

Well, left joins don't remove non matching rows. Shifting the `IS NULL` check from the `ON` to the `WHERE` clause might work.

```
SELECT vtn.*,
       vn.id notice_id,
       vn.vnotice_datetime sent_notice_time
       FROM vtemplates vt 
            LEFT JOIN vtemplate_notices vtn
                      ON vtn.vtemplate_id = vt.id
            LEFT JOIN vnotices vn
                      ON vn.vtemplate_notice_id = vtn.id
            LEFT JOIN violations v
                      ON v.vtemplate_id = vt.id
       WHERE v.id = 1
             AND vn.vnotice_datetime IS NULL;
```

Comment: your query works for sequential order. That's Great! but what If I select 3rd notice direct and 1st two notices are not sent then it shows 1st & 2nd notice. How should I obtain that? Expected: if I did not send first 2 notices and select 3rd then it should show me 3rd, 4th & so on.

Comment: @PranavUnde: So the original question is answered I believe. If you have another question post a new one.